# Where can I find a 'Requires .net 3.5' logo?

Tags: .net

I once found a web site that had some 'Requires .net 1.0', 'Requires .net 2.0' logos for use on web sites etc, does anyone know the name of the site or where I can get something similar?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this logo:

[image]

and then just add the word "requires" on top of it with text or just open this in paint and add it.

Answer (score 4):

We created a series of [Framework Compatibility Icons](http://www.xheo.com/support/kb/1018/assembly+versioning.aspx#fcg) years ago that have been used by a number of people. The download includes required GIF/JPG up to 2.0 but includes the original PhotoShop and Illustrator files that can be used to produce any version you'd like.

Comment: Nice set of images.  Would be even better if they were updated with the new .NET Logo (http://blogs.msdn.com/msmossyblog/archive/2008/10/25/embrace-the-new-net-logo.aspx).

Comment: Broken link, here's the new one:  http://xheo.com/knowledge-base/deploylx/general/assembly-versioning

Answer (score 0):

Not really programming related but I guess you'd probably need to approach Microsoft to legitimately use the logo in your app (unless you create your own logo), they'd supply the artwork no doubt.

Comment: Microsoft unfortunately don't allow the use of any of their icons/artwork (unless explicitly stated) in applications. 

Causes a right pain when you're trying to represent office products but can't use office icons :S

Comment: Hence why I said they'd have to approach Microsoft to get permission, this site is clear about how you should refer to .NET when talking about your application and categoric that you can't use the .NET logo in any way, shape or form on your app or packaging as it's only for MS use (http://www.microsoft.com/about/legal/trademarks/usage/net.mspx). So they need to avoid the suggestions here to take the logo and add "Requires..." to it as well!

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is an official logo. You can just use any o fthe available logos and add "Requires" ;-)